# Using the full width of an Excel chart with two Y-axes

Tags: microsoft-excel, microsoft-excel-2007

I am trying to create a line chart in Microsoft Excel 2007 with two data series, each with their own Y-axis.

First, I create a simple chart by selecting the two data series, and choosing `Insert > Charts > Line` from the Ribbon. I now see the following chart in my workbook:

[image]

I then continue my quest by right clicking one of the data series (lines) and choosing `Format data series > Series Options > Secondary Axis`. My chart is now looks like this:

[image]

This is *almost* what I want. I did not expect to see the gap between the last X-axis tick point (x = 5) and the secondary (right most) Y-axis. Why does Excel introduce this gap?

Is there anything I can do to avoid it? I have tried right clicking the X-axis and seleting `Format Axis > Axis Options > Position Axis: Between tick marks`, but that only introduces a similar gap on by the primary (left most) Y-axis.

---

**UPDATE:** The following data is sufficient for me to reproduce the problem. Paste it into Excel, select the block of numbers and create a line chart. It will not draw the exact same lines as above, but it will illustrate the problem with the right side "padding".

```
1       2       4       8       16
100     210     440     900     2000
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You cannot do what you want with Line Chart, you have to use Scatterplot.

Answer (score 2):

This confounded me for a long time, finally figured out a fix.  On the top bar under *Chart Tools*, select *Layout → Secondary Horizontal Axis* and select the *On Tick Mark* option.

The seconday axis (which in most cases is the same as the primary) will pop up on the chart but it can be then deleted without screwing up the way the chart looks.

Comment: Thank you so much; the comment about using a scatterplot (accepted) did not actually help me. Using this approach you can use regular line and area chart options (or combinations thereof).

Answer (score 0):

The only way I was able to reproduce this issue was by making the source of my lines have one extra row than my x-axis values. Is it possible you are doing that?

Comment: I am not aware that I should have any extra rows. Please, see the update to my question.

Answer (score 0):

I have the same question but using 2013/2016 and there is no "Layout" tab under Chart Tools anymore. Is there any other way to access the "Secondary Horizontal Axis option so I can change its "On Tick Mark" option?

Edit: 
 I had to find my own solution with clues from online for 2013/2016. Go to: Chart Tools -> Add Chart Element -> Axis -> Secondary Horizontal This will separate out the x-axis so that your secondary axis will appear above the chart grid itself.

Right click on that new x-axis and select "Format Axis". Under Axis Options, and Axis Position, you will see the On Tick Marks or Between Tick Marks options. Choose the On Tick Marks.

Then you can go back and turn off the Secondary Horizontal option. This will bring you back to just one normal X-Axis and your lines/areas will stretch from one end of the chart to the other!